# Video Trim software for AVC video

Tags: windows, video-editing

I have a video for which Mediainfo gives the following details:

MPEG-4 (Base Media/Version 2)
1 Video Stream: AVC
1 Audio Stream: AAC

First Video Stream:
372 Kbps (350 Kbps), 550*412 (4:3), at 25.00 fps, AVC (NTSC) (Main@L3.1) (CABAC/3 Ref Frames)

First Audio Stream:
96.0 Kbps, 44.1KHz, 2 channels, AAC (LC)

I want to trim the video from both it's ends - the starting few minutes as well as the last few minutes. Kindly suggest a suitable video editing software which makes the trimmed output file smaller than the untrimmed input file.

I have tried softwares such as Filmora (trial) and Windows Movie Maker. While Filmora ended up giving me a trimmed output file which was twice as big (in terms of file size) as the input file; Windows Movie Maker did not support this file.

I am running Windows-7.

Because I am a student, I'd prefer freeware but I'd be open to consider the paid apps so long as they offer a fully functional trial version to let me test the app exhaustively before making the purchase.

Comment: Do you want to cut on the keyframes or perform smart rendering?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I need to perform smart rendering...I don't want the video quality etc to change. Simply cut-out the first few minutes and the last two minutes.

Comment: Neither cutting on the keyframes nor smart rendering change the video quality. :) But you should update your post since you are asking for smart rendering software, also specifying that you allow paid solutions (since there are no free solutions that do that).

Comment: If neither change the video quality, then let's try both. I said smart rendering because google said that Smart Rendering's best at preventing quality loss!